# Replace Image Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a  image on my web page , i need to replace the image source when i upload a  new image.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("input:file").change(function () {
       if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        var file = $('#file_select')[0].files[0];
        console.log(file.size);
        //console.log(file.width);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var img = new Image();
        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function(_file) {
         img.src= _file.target.result;
        $('#img_preview').append('<img src="'+ img.src +'"/>');
        //console.log(img.src);
        console.log(img.width);
    } 
   }
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file_select">
<div id="img_preview"><img class="thisimage" src="image/01.jpg" alt="image">
 </div>
```

This is my code , I need to replace the first image source with the second uploaded image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
        $('#img_preview').append('<img src="'+ img.src +'"/>');
```

To

```
$('.thisimage').attr('src', img.src);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have `img` element in DOM no need to append a new image element again. Just change `src` of already present `image` as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/eyjcqkc7/)**

```
$('#img_preview #imgpr').attr('src',_file.target.result);
//#imgpr is the id of the image tag
```

Comment: thank you so much sir, its very use ful

Answer (score -1):

Sample

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "hackanm.gif";
```

You can read more about this on : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp

Comment: what how does my answer got -1